# Error with regex for currency

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex which removes everything and leaves just numbers and a dot. It doesn't work for large numbers.

Eg. It works when the £5.99 is put into it i get 5.99
but for bigger numbers like £48.49 I get .49

I want this to work with numbers as big as £100.99

```
/[^0-9.]+([0-9]{2}){0,1}/
```

An input would be something like "this costs £25.95."

The result should be 25.95

Comment: If you explicitly state in your regular expression that you only want to match 2 digits, then that is what you get.

Comment: can't see how that'd return `.`, since you're explicitly excluding `.`. with the `^` in your `[]` char class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
'~(\d+(?:\.\d+))|.~s'
```

and replace with `\1`.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oN5iJ8/1)

This regex replacement will keep only integer and float numbers in the string.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/DivZdK):

```
$re = '~(\d+(?:\.\d+))|.~su'; 
$str = "this costs £25.95."; 
$result = preg_replace($re, '\1', $str);
echo $result;
// => 25.95
```

Comment: it didnt work preg_replace("/(\d+(?:\.\d+))|./","",$rest2); the result is blank

Comment: It works. What is $rest2? Did you use `$re = '~(\d+(?:\.\d+))|.~su';`?